# Fazer upload e download de imagem para pasta do projeto usando Spring Boot

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvento um modulo web que preciso fazer um upload de uma imagem. Fazer salvar na pasta do projeto, estou usando a Commons Io do Apache:

```
public class FileUtil {

    public static void saveFile(String path, MultipartFile file){

        File saveFile = new File(path);
        try {
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(saveFile, file.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

@RequestMapping(value = "/salvar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvar(Event evento, Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
        String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "resources/imagens/" + evento.getName() + ".png";
        FileUtil.saveFile(path, file);
    }
    service.salvar(evento);
    return "redirect:/evento/formulario";
}
```

Ate estou conseguindo salvar, mas como tonar esse caminho em que a imagem foi salva, em um link que possa baixar a imagem e adicionar como atributo da classe Evento?

Comment: Você quer esse link onde, numa página JSP? Qual seria essa classe `Event`? A imagem pode ser acessada de uma forma estática?

Comment: O link seria mostrado em uma coluna de uma tabela numa pagina html, mostrar o link nao e problema, a questao seria como recuperar esse aquivo que foi feito o upload e baixar ele. A classe evento deve possuir uma imagem, porem so estou guardando a referencia da imagem em um atributo da classe. Poderia ser acessada estaticamente sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um método que receba o nome de uma imagem e faça o download dela, exemplo:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    //Lista as imagens dentro da pasta resources/imagem numa JSP
    @RequestMapping("imagens")
    public ModelAndView imagens() throws IOException {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("image-list");
        Set<String> nomeDasImagens = servletContext.getResourcePaths("/resources/imagens/").stream()
                                                    .map(FilenameUtils::getBaseName)
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        mv.addObject("imagens", nomeDasImagens);
        return mv;
    }

    //Faz o download da imagem com o nome informado
    @RequestMapping(value = "download/{nome}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadImage(@PathVariable String nome) {
        InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/imagens/" + nome + ".png");
        if(is == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }

        //Faça o que quiser aqui
        //Como criar um Event e atribuir o nome ou o caminho da imagem a ele

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
                .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nome + ".png")
                .body(new InputStreamResource(is));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Página JSP que lista todas as imagens:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Imagens</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:forEach var="imagem" items="${imagens}">
            <a href="download/${imagem}">${imagem}</a><br />
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Edit:

Para apenas exibir a imagem, você pode remover o header da `ResponseEntity` ficando assim:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(is));
```

Outra opção é acessá-la de forma estática:

Para isso adicione o seguinte método:

```
@RequestMapping("imagens-estaticas")
public ModelAndView imagensEstaticas() throws IOException {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("image-list");
    Map<String, String> nomeDasImagens = servletContext.getResourcePaths("/resources/imagens/").stream()
                                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(FilenameUtils::getBaseName, String::toString));
    mv.addObject("imagens", nomeDasImagens);
    return mv;
}
```

E altere o JSP para:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Imagens</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:forEach var="imagem" items="${imagens}">
            <a href="${imagem.value}">${imagem.key}</a><br />
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Edit 2:

Para você poder fazer o download de imagens em qualquer formato:

```
@RequestMapping("imagens")
public ModelAndView imagens() throws IOException {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("image-list");
    Set<String> nomeDasImagens = servletContext.getResourcePaths("/resources/imagens/").stream()
                                                .map(FilenameUtils::getName)
                                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    mv.addObject("imagens", nomeDasImagens);
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "download/{nome:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadImage(@PathVariable String nome) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/imagens/" + nome);
    if(is == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("image/" + FilenameUtils.getExtension(nome)))
            .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nome)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(is));
}
```

Comment: Nao realiza o download na requisicao. Teria uma forma de apenas exibir a imagem na pagina a partir da url?

Comment: @MarceloHenrique Estranho, nos meus testes, quando clico nos links das imagens, o download é realizado.Editei a resposta para apenas mostrar a imagem e não realizar o download dela.

Comment: Fiz um outro codigo e consegui realizar o download. Irei testar agora esse de apenas visualizacao..

Comment: Seu codigo esta correto, eu que fiz uma coisa errada. Obrigado! Nesse caso, o unico formato que eu poderia salvar na pasta seria o PNG, por casua do MediaType? Ou apenas trocar pela opcao ALL ja resolveria?

Comment: @MarceloHenrique No exemplo que dei, coloquei só no formato PNG porque foi o formato que você está salvando segundo o código na sua pergunta. Não seria necessário mudar para `MediaType.ALL`, porém você teria que passar extensão do arquivo junto ao nome e definir o `MediaType` de acordo com o formato do arquivo. Editei minha pergunta e coloquei um exemplo.